# How can I insert XML data into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to grab data from an XML status file that is on VLC and I want to put it into an HTML so that when the status XML updates or is requested, the new information appears in the HTML.

Here is the XML information from the `status.xml` when its ran.
OMFG - I can't post images due to reputation yet. Here are the links to the images instead.

[image]

I want those fields in here:

[image]

I don't have any knowledge of any direct programming. I have run some batch files and I have some python scripts I use and I edit but nothing else. I understand tags, functions and lists to a degree.

I have tried using "scr" to path out my xml file with "type:text/xml. - failed
I have tried using a viewer.js file and editing that to point to the xml file I wanted. - failed. - I didn't understand how to put the xml data into a javascript file that can then be referenced inside the html.

This is the html file; I got it from the rig-developer kit from twitch as there first extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Viewer Page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <div id="app" class="full-height"></div>
        <script src="https://extension-files.twitch.tv/helper/v1/twitch-ext.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="viewer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="http://192.168.0.22:8080/requests/status.xml">{
        </script>
        <h2>Video Game Music playlist</h2>
        <p>Here is what is playing currently</p>
        <div>
            <input type="button"  value="Refresh what's playing" />
        </div>
        <div id="list">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the xml file:
    ]]?>

```
<?vlc

--package.loaded.httprequests = nil --uncomment to debug changes
require "httprequests"

httprequests.processcommands()

local statusTable=httprequests.getstatus(false)

print('<root>\n')


local item = vlc.input.item()

--data in the information section is presented in a non-standard way to             keep compatibility.

?>
<information>
    <category name="meta">
    <?vlc
      if item then
        local metas = item:metas()
        for k,v in pairs(metas) do
          local metadataContent = vlc.strings.convert_xml_special_chars(     httprequests.xmlString(v) )
          print("<info     name='"..httprequests.xmlString(k).."'>"..metadataContent.."</info>")
        end
      end
    ?>
    </category>
  </information>
</root>
```

I excepted that I can find a way to put the data from the xml into the html or any html file. Infact if someone can just show me how to put the xml data I have into an html file where it can be updated that would be amazing.

I have been trying to look up the easiest way to do this on youtube but I keep coming accross videos that show how to get images from xml to html; which I don't need.

Infact, to be honest; I think I need the xml file to be in Javascript first or something? I think the html has to be an inline html and thus the xml data has to be referenced from a .JS file?

I don't know what I am talking about. lol

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Just show what's written in the file? Treat it as HTML? Execute some code in it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? - I am trying to get the Title, artists, date, and name data from VLC and put it into an html for  Twitch. I have set VLC player to run from HTTP so I can control it through the network with a gui interface. I noticed it had a "Status" xml and when I run the xml it shows me all the video data. If I can somehow get that data into html, I can see it as a web extension on twitch. (which a little bit of cleanup I would assume). I know its weird to explain. I am sorry.

I don't believe I can write what is in the status file into the actual html itself.

Comment: The reason I don't believe I can write what is in the status file XML into the actual HTML is because the Status file looks like it can only be ran from the folder its in. It has some vlc functions (I assume) that are in it. Also I want to apologize again for probably not explaining my issue correctly.  If I find a work around or am able to explain myself better I will write a solution. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing XML and HTML is tricky. There's a W3C task group report here which analyzes what works and what doesn't:

https://www.w3.org/2010/html-xml/snapshot/report.html

and an overview talk by Norm Walsh:

https://norman.walsh.name/2011/03/26/HTML-XML-Prague

This work was done some years ago but I don't think the situation has fundamentally changed.

Comment: Re the links, this is fine imo - even if they break you've given enough context to find the resources,and the resources are too large to just dump in an answer.