# In HTML with XML syntax, can one use elements with namespaces other than HTML, SVG and MathML?

Tags: html, xml, syntax, xhtml, specifications

It has long been my understanding that one advantage of the XML syntax for writing HTML documents is that it also permits to include in HTML documents elements with a namespace that is not one of those specified by the HTML standard. For example, user-created elements in a user-created namespace describing books. But, reading the WhatWG specs, this seems to be forbidden, or I do not find how to do it (I mean, in a way that is conforming to the specs).

I am thinking about something similar to the following document.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    …
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <book xmlns="http://example.com/my-book-namespace">
      …
    </book>
  </body>
</html>
```

I realize that of course the browser would not know how to render such elements coming from unknown namespaces, but this may not be a problem (I expect browsers would simply ignore such elements). For example, some javascript on the page could use such elements as data in order to generate HTML elements dynamically.

For example, [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/true-abstraction:-composite-ui-components-in-jsf-20-part-1) about Java Server Faces includes elements in the JSF namespace in what seems to be intended as a conforming XHTML page.

But the specs seems to imply that such an example would be non conforming, and even, that there may be no way of including such elements in an HTML document. “The exact allowed contents of each individual element depend on the content model of that element, as described earlier in this specification. Elements must not contain content that their content model disallows.” ([elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2)); and the [`body` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-body-element) specifies only [Flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#flow-content) as Content model; which does not seem to permit using elements outside of those explicitly specified by the HTML specification.

So, if I insist in producing only spec-conforming HTML documents, should I refrain from including in an HTML document elements from a namespace different from the HTML, SVG and MathML namespaces?

Comment: It's not clear if you are talking about XHTML (which is XML, not HTML) or HTML (which is, unsurprisingly, HTML, not XML). You can only legally embed *other* XML in XHTML  (although what's legal as per the spec, and what browsers let you get away with is another question altogether). Your spec links go to the WhatWG, and they don't concern themselves with XHTML - that's the W3C's turf. So as I said, it's not clear whether you're talking about XHTML or HTML.

Comment: I am talking about the [XML syntax for HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-xhtml-syntax), as this phrase is used by the WhatWG spec, which they consider as the same thing as XHTML: “The XML syntax for HTML was formerly referred to as ‘XHTML’, but this specification does not use that term (among other reasons, because no such term is used for the HTML syntaxes of MathML and SVG).” If you have another definition in mind for XHTML, please give me some details so that we can be sure we talk about the same thing.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554299/how-can-i-insert-xml-data-into-html but I'm not closing as a duplicate because that question doesn't have a definitive answer.

Comment: I guess ultimately the question is moot, because ultimately HTML has always been driven by what browsers allow you to do, and the spec followed. HTML validity was never a hard requirement in real life, and striving for it has never bought you anything (as opposed to XML, where invalid source code fails parsing). Browsers do not really care about the declared DOCTYPE, and work under a "best-effort parsing" principle under all circumstances. Even if a fully fleshed-out spec would exist, it would not be followed by anyone to any meaningful degree or consequence.

Comment: You are correct. You cannot embed elements from other namespaces in a _conforming_ XHTML document. But that's more just about the nature of conformance than it is a usage requirement. Browsers will treat elements from other namespaces just like they were spans, i.e. no special behaviours, take the initial values of all CSS properties. It's for you to establish your own conformance rules for your hybrid XHTML+book document. That's normal and how it's intended to work.

Comment: Thanks @Alohci. If you can indicate where the specs prescribe the browser behavior that you describe (if you take this from the specs), and back up the claim about the current situation being “normal and the way it is intended to work” with some authoritative statement, I think it would make a useful answer! I find it strange and unpleasant that “compliant” and “how I should use it” be two different things (for example, I expect that tools that check compliance for me would help me create effectively useful documents).

Answer (score 0):

While WHATWG's HTML spec indeed states that

> Elements must not contain content that their content model disallows.

as you cited, chapter 13.2.6.4.7 (The "in body" insertion mode) states the actual action that HTML parsers are supposed to perform on your example doc:

> Any other start tag:
> Insert an HTML element for the token

(https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-main-inbody).

And even though the parsing rules given in chapter 13 grossly mix error recovery and SGML-style tag inference actions (the latter only applying to HTML serialization), in the absence of other rules they should apply to XML content as well (or none of the grammar rules could apply to XML at all).

Consequently, browsers won't ignore your `book` element but will treat it according to [13.2.6.1 Creating and inserting nodes - Insert a foreign element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#insert-a-foreign-element). If your doc had actual `book` content such as in the following example,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <book xmlns="http://example.com/my-book-namespace">
      <descr xmlns="http://example.com/my-book-namespace">
        some text
      </descr>
    </book>
  </body>
</html>
```

browsers will render the `descr` text content as unstyled content, but you could style it using CSS `@namespace` rules like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <style>
     @namespace url(http://example.com/my-book-namespace);
     descr { color: blue }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <book xmlns="http://example.com/my-book-namespace">
      <descr xmlns="http://example.com/my-book-namespace">
        some text
      </descr>
    </book>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. None of Section 13 applies to the XML syntax of HTML. Section 14 applies instead.

Comment: Thanks @imhotap. Seems to me that @Alohci’s comment is correct. Section 13 header indicates: “This section only describes the rules for resources labeled with an HTML MIME type. Rules for XML resources are discussed in the section below entitled ‘The XML syntax’.” Care to comment?

Comment: @Olivier Cailloux All I can say is that if the example I've given works (and it does in Chrome and FF), and WHATWG's spec doesn't explain that behavior, then probably the spec doesn't hold up against quality standards we've come to expect for XML